# How can I calculate an equation represented by a series of nodes in this Polymorphism exercise?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand how the code in this Polymorphism exercise works.

I think I understand the concept; however, I'm having trouble understanding how to apply it to the equation: `1 + 2 * 3`

```
abstract class Node {
    abstract double evaluate();
}

public class ValueNode extends Node {
    double value;

    double evaluate() {
        return value;
    }
}

public abstract class OpNode extends Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;

    abstract double evaluate();
}

public class MultiplicationNode extends OpNode {
    double evaluate() {
        return left.evaluate() * right.evaluate();
    }
}

public class AdditionNode extends OpNode {
    double evaluate() {
        return left.evaluate() + right.evaluate();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Comment: im just a little confused, and this isnt realy was the point of the question mr. crush.

Comment: Try to make your questions clear and concise. It's unclear what you are asking if it's not about `@Override` annotation. Also, providing cleanly formatted code in your question will go a long ways towards people actually reading it.

Comment: The (non-abstract) classes need constructors.  If those were there, you might be able to come up with the answer more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note*** It seems to me that `Node` would be more appropriately defined as an `interface` in this context. Are you sure that it's not meant to be an `interface` instead of an `abstract class`?

---

You are attempting to represent the equation

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

According to your code, you have two types of `Node`:

- `ValueNode` - represents a value
- `OpNode` - represents an operation

Therefore, according to your equation, you have 5 nodes:

```
ValueNode = 1
AdditionNode = +
ValueNode = 2
MultiplicationNode = *
ValueNode = 3
```

Note that `AdditionNode` and `MultiplicationNode` are types of `OpNode`.

Each `OpNode` refers to a left `Node` and a right `Node`. It's important to understand that either of these `Node`'s can be a `ValueNode` or an `OpNode`.

Don't forget order of operations, though. Multiplication comes before Addition.

So, when you represent this relationship as a series of nodes, you need to keep that in mind.

If you had the proper constructors on your code (you don't), you'd do the following with Dependency Injection:

```
Node node = new AdditionNode(
    new ValueNode(1),
    new MultiplicationNode(
        new ValueNode(2),
        new ValueNode(3)
    )
);
```

Now, when you call

```
node.evaluate();
```

You will get the answer to the equation.

---

Your constructors should look like this:

```
class ValueNode {
    double value;

    public ValueNode(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class OpNode {
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public OpNode(Node left, Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

---

Here is a working example: http://ideone.com/oCVR8S

Answer (score 0):

The @Override annotations should be above any methods that are overridden from a subclass' or interface's method.